# Cannot do anything while writing to a SourceDataLine

Tags: java, audio, jcomponent, javax.sound.sampled

I am somewhat new to audio in Java. What I am trying to do is as I am playing audio, I want to repaint my `JComponent`, but the `SourceDataLine` blocks all other lines of code including other Threads.
Here is my `play()` method

```
public void play()
{
    final AudioFormat af =new AudioFormat(Note.SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, true);
    SourceDataLine line;
    try {
        line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        line.open(af, Note.SAMPLE_RATE);
        line.start();
        byte[] arr=data;
        for(int position=0;position<arr.length;position++)
        {
            byte[] out={arr[position]};
            line.write(out, 0, 1);        //Blocks all user input (Mouse and Keyboard)
            this.repaint();               //Need to repaint JComponent here
        }
        line.drain();
        line.close();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently you're calling `play` on [the Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). For example, maybe you call it from an action event generated by a button press. You need to start a new thread for the playback loop, otherwise nothing can happen on the GUI until playback ends.

At the very least, something like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        play();
    }
}).start();
```

However, you should read some concurrency tutorials (like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)) as it seems you will be accessing fields across different threads (such as whatever `byte[] arr = data;` is).

You may also wish to use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) which has some integration with Swing. I have a somewhat lengthier code example online that shows an example of a playback loop using SwingWorker: [WaveformDemo](https://github.com/Radiodef/WaveformDemo/blob/master/waveformdemo/WaveformDemo.java). The playback loop is around line 310.